# creating entities modeling two football teams playing against each other using hibernate/ JPA annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am in the process of building a sports team database, and i am stuck on how to model two teams playing against each other. these are the tables in the db currently using a many to many relationship between teams and games.

```
public class FootballTeam {

private FootballTeam(){/**/}

public FootballTeam(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long teamId;

private String teamName;

@Embedded
private Location teamLocation;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "favoriteTeams")
private List<Users> fans = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "teams")
private List<FootballGame> schedule = new ArrayList<>();


public List<FootballGame> getSchedule() {
    return schedule;
}

public void setSchedule(List<FootballGame> schedule) {
    this.schedule = schedule;
}

public List<Users> getFans() {
    return fans;
}

public void setFans(List<Users> fans) {
    this.fans = fans;
}

public Long getTeamId() {
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(Long teamId) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
}

public Location getTeamLocation() {
    return teamLocation;
}

public void setTeamLocation(Location teamLocation) {
    this.teamLocation = teamLocation;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
}
```

and Game.java

```
public class FootballGame {

private FootballGame(){/**/}

public FootballGame(Date playedOn, List<FootballTeam> teams) {
    this.playedOn = playedOn;
    this.teams = teams;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long gameId;

private Date playedOn;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "teams_play_games",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gameId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "schedule"))
private List<FootballTeam> teams = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getGameId() {
    return gameId;
}

public void setGameId(Long gameId) {
    this.gameId = gameId;
}

public Date getPlayedOn() {
    return playedOn;
}

public void setPlayedOn(Date playedOn) {
    this.playedOn = playedOn;
}

public List<FootballTeam> getTeams() {
    return teams;
}

public void setTeams(List<FootballTeam> teams) {
    this.teams = teams;
}
}
```

what I can't seem to figure out is how to store each of the two teams as homeTeam and visitingTeam rather than just a list of teams. I know that a List preserves order, but is there a more definitive way?

Comment: Using homeTeam and visitingTeam references in the FootballGame makes way more sense. You could have "homeGames" and "awayGames" in the Team class (bidirectional with homeTeam, visitingTeam), or just use the schedule list you have (but this is not then bidirectional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think, an easy solution would be to add the `hostingTeam` to the `FootballGame` class.
The visiting could be figured out from the join table `teams_play_games` using the `gameId` of the relevant football game.

```
@Entity
public class FootballGame {
    ....    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "hosting_team")
    private FootballTeam hostingTeam;
```

Hope this helps & share your thoughts.

Comment: can i tie both hosting_team and visiting_team back to the same list in Team using two join columns?

Comment: @StillLearningToCode: Yes you can do that. But I thought having only one team as `hosting_team` would be enough since the join table `teams_play_games` contains the 2 teams for a particular game and you could figure out the other team from that join table.